# if website id number is 0 add lang line codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

If the website id  **0** I would like to add `$this->lang->line('text_default');` otherwise does not show that lang line. Currently it shows on all of them.

How can I get it to only display `$this->lang->line('text_default)` if `$website['website_id'] = number 0`

For some reason it thinks `0` is `false`.

```
<?php if ($website['website_id'] = 0) {?>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $website['name'];?> </td>
<?php } else { ?>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $website['name'] . $this->lang->line('text_default'); ?> </td>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a double equal sign:

**FROM:** `($website['website_id'] = 0)`

**TO:** `($website['website_id'] == 0)`

```
<?php if ($website['website_id'] == 0) {?>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $website['name'];?> </td>
<?php } else { ?>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $website['name'] . $this->lang->line('text_default'); ?> </td>
<?php } ?>
```

StackOverflow regarding operators: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
<?php if ($website['website_id'] = 0) { ?>
```

This is wrong, use a comparisation operator instead of an assignment.

```
<?php if ($website['website_id'] == 0) {?>
```

You overwrote your $website["website_id"] with 0 and same turn you forced your if-expresion to be always true.

This happens when you place only one "=", a very common beginner mistake.

However I cannot tell you wether 0 is right or wrong because I dont know codeigniter and what is stored in $website["website_id"], or even if its always filled. Incase its still not working analyze the variable with

```
var_dump($website['website_id']);
```

and do different page calls.